# zend getting multiple url param with redirect

Tags: php, zend-framework

how can i get an url params along with redirect url for zend php framework? 
lets say i have the following URL on current page

```
localhost/business/microsoft
```

when a user click a button on that page it will redirect them to another page with the following url

```
 localhost/comment/WavvLdfdP6g8aZTtbBQHTw?return_url=%2Fbusiness%2FWavvLdfdP6g8aZTtbBQHTw
```

how i can write bootstrap getRouter so it can catch the above url params? the current one seems not doing well

```
$router->addRoute('comment', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
            'business/comment/id=',
            array(
                'controller' => 'business',
                'action'     => 'comment'
            )
            , array(
                'id' => '\d+'
            )
        ));
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to write a [plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) that captures the request parameters either before (*preDispatch()*) or after dispatch (*postDispatch()*) depending on whether or not you might want to intercept and redirect the request.

```
//basic example of controller plugin
class MyPlugin extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        return $this->getRequest->getParams();
    }
}
```

Then [register your plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.using).